# What are the differences between [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] and [@[] mutableCopy]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

vs

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [@[] mutableCopy]
```

What are the differences between declaring arrays in these two separate ways?

Comment: The second one creates two objects.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the 2nd line as:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[[NSArray alloc] init] mutableCopy];
```

So the clear difference is the 1st way is more efficient and the 2nd way needlessly creates an extra object that is promptly discarded.

Comment: Actually, it's `[[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ... ] mutableCopy]`  see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: @danh OK but it's the same basic issue.

Comment: Yes, it's a nit. Just suggesting a level of precision that you typically provide :-)